# Creating a custom format type in Struct

Tags: python, struct

I am trying to decode binary data from a socket connection into python datatypes (ints, floats, etc) using Struct. This works fine for +90% of the cases. My problem is that a few of the binary streams contain non-standard data types (e.g. 6 byte int).

What i would like to do is define a custom datatype to handle these cases. In the following example, 'e' is my custom 6 byte int

The command
`struct.unpack('heH', binary_data)`

would yield:
(int_2b_var, int_6b_var, uint_2b_var)

How would I go about this? 
Thanks